# PHP compiler optimization

Tags: php

For a website in PHP I was searching Php compilers(I know it is parsed).Could'nt find any except HIPHOP from Facebook.I'm not talking about conversion to binary,I am interested in the optimization tasks a compiler performs so that I can optimize my PHP.Like removing extra variables,unused variables,statements inside loops,optimize expressions etc. Are there any such programs available?

Comment: First of all, why would you declare variables that are unused? I would suggest that you use an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse that will highlight any variables that are currently unused.

Comment: @Daniel I was just giving an example.A compiler performs many more optimizations.Ya I do use eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are searching for PHP optimizers like [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php), eAccelerator, Zend Optimizer and [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) and not for a compiller

Comment: No,I am not talking bout APCs,I am just talking bout local code enhancement using a tool like a compiler.APCs cant perform most of the tasks a compiler can.